# How can I show PowerShell error message on the console and write them to the log?

Tags: powershell

In the following excerpt from a function that I am working on there are 4 calls to the `Tee-Object` cmdlet. The first 3 write the messages to the console and the log as I wanted. The 4th one uses `Write-Error` and it only writes to the console.

```
# Run this step if the last step was successful...
if($script:BuildStepLastStatus -eq 0) {


    Write-Output $("`n" + "-"*100) | Tee-Object -FilePath  $script:BuildLogFileName -Append
    Write-Output ("[{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}]: Step {1}..." -f (Get-Date), $StepName) | Tee-Object -FilePath  $script:BuildLogFileName -Append

    try {
        . $ScriptBlock | Tee-Object -FilePath  $script:BuildLogFileName -Append
    }
    catch {

        # Show the error details whether we will continue on error or not...
        Write-Error "$($_)`n" | Tee-Object -FilePath  $script:BuildLogFileName -Append

        if($ContinueOnError.IsPresent) {
            # 0 = success
            $script:BuildStepLastStatus = 0
        }
        else {
            # 1 = error condition
            $script:BuildStepLastStatus = 1
        }
    }
}
```

How can I modify this code to write errors to the console and the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `Tee-Object` accepts the contents from output stream, hence errors from error stream will be ignored. You can do the inverse.

```
"$($_)`n" | Tee-Object -FilePath  $script:BuildLogFileName -Append | Write-Error
```

Comment: I ended using a variation on this method. I'm not sure that using Write-Error from inside a catch block is even a good idea anyway. Most example of Write-Error I see are cases where it used to cause an error to happen that will then be caught by a catch block.

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at Redirection??

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/

Comment: I did look into this. It ended up not applying in this specific situation but those are both very useful references.

Comment: Just thinking you could have redirected the error stream to the output stream and then Tee'd the output stream as you'd done previously.